# How to Install SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Silently In InstallShield 2015

Tags: sql-server-2008, installshield, silent-installer

I am trying below command line for the same but when start the installation its showing the sql screens.how to make silent of sql installation please. i know lots of answer on the web but no one working. i am using vs2012 wpf and sql server 2008 r2 express. please help.

SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe/QS/Action=Install/Hideconsole/IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS/SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck/FEATURES=SQLENGINE/InstanceName=SQLEXPRESS/AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service"/AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic/SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service"/ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service"/SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="Builtin\Administrators"/BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic/SECURITYMODE=SQL/SAPWD=cptams/ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=True/TCPENABLED=1/ENABLERANU=True

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @jason Hughes- not getting such any error, showing sql installation screen. but i want to install sql in silent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For unattended installation add `/Q`

> **/Q**
>   Specifies that Setup runs in a quiet mode without any user interface. This is used for unattended installations.

2. Use [configuation file](http://mssqlfun.com/2013/01/29/sql-server-silent-unattended-installation-using-configuration-file/) and set in configuration.ini `QUIET="True"`

Comment: I added /QUIET=True but no luck , still showing sql screen... please help

Comment: @JasRajBishnoi Does it help?

Answer (score -1):

```
q /INDICATEPROGRESS="False" /ACTION=Install /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="True" /QUIET="True" /SkipRules=RebootRequiredCheck /FEATURES=SQL,RS,BIDS,Conn,BC,SDK,BOL,SSMS,ADV_SSMS,SNAC_SDK,OCS /INSTANCENAME="SQLEXPRESS" /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled" /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" /SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /RSSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /ISSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" /ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /TCPENABLED="0" /NPENABLED="0" /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=Automatic /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=123456 /RSINSTALLMODE=FilesOnlyMode /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="\Everyone"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this answer may be correct, please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves.